# PHP regex matches timestamp but not when part of script tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex pattern that is close to working but I'm still missing something. I want to swap out only the timestamp of a `<script>` tag's `src`:

So I want this:

```
stuff BEFORE...<script src='/assets/mySite-1238459846.js'></script>
stuff AFTER...
```

to be this:

```
stuff BEFORE...<script src='/assets/mySite-0123456789.js'></script>
stuff AFTER...
```

Here's the code which switches the timestamp but only when with `src` doesn't contain any special characters or slashes, meaning only `$stringNotSpecial` works:

```
$stringNotSpecial='mySite-1238459846.js'; //Works!
$stringSpecial='stuff BEFORE...<script src='/assets/mySite-0123456789.js'></script>
stuff AFTER...'; //DOESNT work :(
$timestamp='0123456789';
$pattern = '/mySite-[0-9]+.js/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'mySite-'.$timestamp.'.js', $stringNotSpecial);
echo '<br>';
echo echo preg_replace($pattern, 'mySite-'.$timestamp.'.js', $stringSpecial);
```

Comment: That code would error out because you need src='/assets/mySite-0123456789.js' to be in double quotes.
Plus your code doesn't make sense because you can just as easily generate the string by concatenating 'mySite-' to the timestamp.

Comment: Might go nowhere, but try replacing the / in $pattern with % and see what happens

Comment: @silkfire double quotes have no effect: http://writecodeonline.com/php/. Also, I won't know what the prior timestamp (`1238459846` is just an example) is when the code runs so that is why I have to search for it.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$stringSpecial='stuff BEFORE...<script src=\'/assets/mySite-0123456789.js\'></script>stuff AFTER...';
```

or

```
$stringSpecial='stuff BEFORE...<script src="/assets/mySite-0123456789.js"></script>stuff AFTER...';
```

From the output of http://ideone.com/Vq8TSS -

```
result: Success     time: 0.01s    memory: 20520 kB     returned value: 0
input: no
output:

mySite-0123456789.js<br>stuff BEFORE...<script src='/assets/mySite-0123456789.js'></script>stuff AFTER...
```

Comment: What is the point of the url in comment? And I have corrected the obvious mistake in the code. What error do you get? What is the output?

Comment: Updated the answer to show that it works. PS: You have 2 `echo` in last line